# Is there an analytical chemistry alternative to the Scoville scale for the hotness of chilli?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

The traditional way of measuring the perceived heat of a chilli is the [Scoville scale](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scoville_scale) which involves panel testing of diluted extracts taken from chilli. But panels are very variable and the results appear to be a little unreliable.

But we know the class of chemicals that creates the sensation of heat: capsaicinoids. Can't we just measure those directly?

Is there a better analytical method for measuring the heat of a chilli?

Answer (score 5):

Matt did find a method that uses HPLC on the peppers alone, not in a dish.

So given that the capsaicinoids is a class of compounds, each different capsaicinoid would have a different perceived hotness. So a chemical test would measure the concentration of each type capsaicinoid and then use a weighted average over the human perceived hotness for each member of the capsaicinoid class.

Comment: Apparently not everyone agrees. See [this on fivethirtyeight.](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/rating-chili-peppers-on-a-scale-of-1-to-oh-dear-god-im-on-fire/)